# App builds successfully, but fails to deploy on digital ocean

Tags: reactjs, laravel, deployment, digital-ocean

I have developed a web application using React and Laravel, and it runs smoothly on my local machine. I am trying to deploy it quickly on Digital Ocean. Although the application builds without any errors, it fails to deploy correctly. When I deployed it for the first time, the page was blank, and the developer tools showed an error message. I am struggling to identify the root cause of this issue.
I will appreciate it if anyone who has experinced it beofre pinpoints for me where the issue might be.

[image]

Comment: did you implement SSL certification on your proxy server? or refer to this [site](https://web.dev/fixing-mixed-content/)